# Multi-line field with more than 500 text lines

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to create announcement list that should allow users to add long description content (around 500 text lines).

I read the following information from "Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013" MSDN article:

> List row size is 8,000 bytes per row" and "Multiple Lines of Text 192 "

What does it mean? I can't create list item with multi-line field and fill this field with more than 192 line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only references how the data (column) is being stored in SQL Server, not the lines of text stored in the column itself.

> SharePoint Server 2013 data is stored in SQL Server tables. To allow for the maximum number of possible columns in a SharePoint list, SharePoint Server 2013 will create several rows in the database when data will not fit on a single row. This is called row wrapping.
>
> SQL Server row wrapping occurs after each 32 columns in a SharePoint list. The default row wrapping value of six allows for a maximum of 192 Multiple lines of text columns per SharePoint list (6 * 32 = 192).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Column

Comment: Can you please add sources for your citations? Link to the relevant page for example

Comment: Wish Granted...

Comment: Perfect, it makes your answer much better (and also it is important to grant credit to authors of content)

Comment: @jpollar thank you, then how much line I can enter to the Multiple lines field? I'm wandering because of "List row size is 8,000 bytes per row"

Comment: It's more based on characters.

"A Multiple lines of text column can store as many as 63,999 characters, and you can specify the number of lines of text that you want to display when people enter information about an item."

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7#__toc277149822